# Put last 3 entries for each column into a new dataframe when number of columns is variable

Tags: r

I have a DF that lists IDs by date like this:

```
Date          Ben     James
12/10/17      1294    NA     
12/11/17      NA      4523      
12/12/17      8959    3246      
12/13/17      2345    NA        
12/14/17      NA      NA        
12/15/17      0303    8877      
12/16/17      NA      1427
```

The number of "name" columns is variable, so on another day I might have a DF that looks like this:

```
Date          Ben     James     Alex
12/10/17      1294    NA        3754
12/11/17      NA      4523      1122
12/12/17      8959    3246      5582
12/13/17      2345    NA        NA
12/14/17      NA      NA        0094
12/15/17      0303    8877      NA
12/16/17      NA      1427      NA
```

I want to put the 3 most recent IDs for each name column into a new dataframe, like this:

```
IDs
8959
2345
0303
3246
8877
1427
1122
5582
0094
```

I just need the IDs in the new DF. I don't care about labeling them by name or date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c(sapply(df[-1], function(x) sprintf("%04d", tail(x[!is.na(x)], 3))))
#[1] "8959" "2345" "0303" "3246" "8877" "1427" "1122" "5582" "0094"
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(Date = c("12/10/17", "12/11/17", "12/12/17", "12/13/17", 
"12/14/17", "12/15/17", "12/16/17"), Ben = c(1294L, NA, 8959L, 
2345L, NA, 303L, NA), James = c(NA, 4523L, 3246L, NA, NA, 8877L, 
1427L), Alex = c(3754L, 1122L, 5582L, NA, 94L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Ben", "James", "Alex"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res <- do.call(rbind, 
               apply(df[, -1], 2, function(x) data.frame(IDs = tail(na.omit(x), 3))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   summarise_at(vars(-one_of('Date')), funs(list(tail(.[!is.na(.)], 3)))) %>%
   unlist(., use.names = FALSE) %>%
   str_pad(width = 4, pad=0)
#[1] "8959" "2345" "0303" "3246" "8877" "1427" "1122" "5582" "0094"
```